# Rails - f.select and strange syntax error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, syntax

I use following `f.select` query:

```
= f.select(:category_id, @categories, :html_options => {:class => 'select_box'}, {:disabled => lambda{ |category| category.id == 18 }})
```

And this line return me a syntax error... why? All braces should be closed...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
= f.select(:category_id, @categories, :html_options => {:class => 'select_box'}, {:disabled => lambda{ |category| category.id == 18 }})
```

should be

```
= f.select(:category_id, @categories, :html_options => {:class => 'select_box', :disabled => lambda{ |category| category.id == 18 }})
```

You had the disabled option in its own hash

Answer (score 1):

According to the api, the method is defined as

```
f.select(method, choices, options = {}, html_options = {})
```

where `:disabled` is an option and `:class` would be an html_option, so the call should probably be written as

```
f.select(:category_id, @categories, {:disabled => lambda{ |category| category.id == 18 }}, { :class => 'select_box' }).
```

The last set of brackets shouldn't be necessary, though.